# Цикл For в игре "Hangman"

Tags: python, python-3.x, циклы, for

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LzkVm.jpg

Основная цель:

У игрока 8 попыток отгадать загаданное слово. За каждую введению букву -1 попытка.

У меня есть рабочая часть выбора слова.

Мне посоветовали примерно такой алгоритм дальнейших действий:

1. Отображение замаскированного слова;
2. Проверить, все ли буквы угаданы, и выйти из цикла;
3. Получить новую букву и поместить ее вспиаок введенных букв;
4. Проверить, есть ли буква в загаданное слове;
5. Отнять по одной попытке при угадывании букв;
6. Выйти, если попыток не осталось;
7. Оповестить игрока приведенными в задании фразами.

Когда я запускаю код, то он распечатывает кучу знаков "-", а должно быть как в примере в ссылке. Видимо, проблема в строке
`for i in hint:`

Собственно, сам код:

```
import random
list_for_game = ['python', 'java', 'kotlin', 'javascript']
computer_choice = random.choice(list_for_game)
hint = len(computer_choice) * "-"

print("H A N G M A N")
print(hint)

attempt = 8
while attempt > 0:
    letter = input("Input a letter:")
    output = len(computer_choice)*"-"
    for i in hint:
        output += len(computer_choice)*"-"
    variable = 0
    for i in computer_choice:
        if i == letter:
            output[variable] = letter
        variable += 1
        print(output)
    if i not in computer_choice:
        attempt -= 1
        print("That letter doesn't appear in the word")
print("Thanks for playing!") 
print("We'll see how well you did in the next stage")
```

Comment: что мешает вам проверить собственное предпложение?

Comment: @Эникейщик , я не знаю, что и как исправить. Поэтому спрашиваю. Изначально у меня вообще было ```for i in range (hint):```  Но писал, что :
TypeError: объект 'str' нельзя интерпретировать, как целое число.

Comment: если кажется, что ошибка в ``for i in hint:``, то попробуйте сконцентрироваться на этом цикле и разобраться, что в нем происходит. Одна из ошибок действительно в этом цикел.

Comment: @Эникейщик , "одна из"...((( А где ещё?! Подскажите, пожалуйста!!!

Comment: ну, например, если ввести букву, которая есть в слове, то программы вылетает с ошибкой

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Хочу немного обновить свой ответ. В этом куске кода проблем я не нашел:

```
import random
list_for_game = ['python', 'java', 'kotlin', 'javascript']
computer_choice = random.choice(list_for_game)
hint = len(computer_choice) * "-"
```

Далее, здесь не понятно, зачем печать hint один раз и в дальнейшем использовать его как нулевую заготовку, в которой всегда будут значения '----' разной длины.

```
print("H A N G M A N")
print(hint)
```

Здесь также вопросов нет, до того момента, как вы в переменную output не начали на каждый ход пихать значения '-----'

```
attempt = 8
while attempt > 0:
    letter = input("Input a letter:")
    output = len(computer_choice)*"-"
for i in hint:
    output += len(computer_choice)*"-"
```

Как показано дальше, вы сравниваете букву с загаданным словом и присваиваете в **массив** который не был объявлен как массив, букву и сразу же печатаете output вне условия и внутри цикла, т.е. столько раз, сколько делается цикл.

```
variable = 0
for i in computer_choice:
    if i == letter:
        output[variable] = letter
    variable += 1
    print(output)
```

Ну и финальная часть, где нет никакой проверки на то, угадал ли пользователь слово или нет. Например я за четыре хода написал java и программа будет предлагать ввести букву, пока не закончатся попытки.

```
if i not in computer_choice:
        attempt -= 1
        print("That letter doesn't appear in the word")
print("Thanks for playing!") 
print("We'll see how well you did in the next stage")
```

Как итог, ваш код с правками

```
import random
list_for_game = ['python', 'java', 'kotlin', 'javascript']
computer_choice = random.choice(list_for_game)
hint = len(computer_choice) * "-"
print("H A N G M A N")

attempt = 8
while attempt > 0:
    print(hint, 'you have ',attempt, 'try') #печатаем hint внутри цикла и выведем сколько осталось попыток
    letter = input("Input a letter:")
    output = ['_']*len(computer_choice) #объявляет output как массив заполненый '-'
    for k,i in enumerate(hint): #добавляем счетчик, чтобы обращаться к конкретному элементу
        output[k] = i
    for j,i in enumerate(computer_choice): #также добавляем счетчик.
        if i == letter:
            output[j] = letter
    if letter not in computer_choice:
        attempt -= 1
        print("That letter doesn't appear in the word")
    hint = ''.join(output) #обновляем hint. И при желании ставим условие на полное отгадывание загаданого слова
    if hint == computer_choice: #то маленькое условие
        print("Thanks for playing!") 
        print("We'll see how well you did in the next stage")
        break
```

Comment: wow!!! Вот это развернутый ответ!!!! Это просто подарок для меня!!!!!! Спасииииибо огромное :* :* :*

Comment: я уже убилась с этой задачей. Полностью разобрала ваш код, добавила пустые строки, которые просит задание и ещё одно маленькое условие. Но система все равно пишет, что "В программе закончились вводимые данные. Вы пытались прочитать больше, чем ожидалось". И правда, почему-то она выводит 21 попытку, вместо того, чтоб выйти после восьмой((( Я пробовала добавить break, но не помогло(((

Comment: Если внимательно посмотреть на условие, то он сравнивает переменную i с изначальным загаданым словом. А что за переменная i ему не известно и я не поправил. Заменим на letter, должно помочь.

Comment: самое интересное, что код на replit.com прекрасно работает, выполняет все условия и печатает так, как требуют. Но когда запускаю на сайте, где должны проверить задание (JetBrains.com), то ему слишком много вводов, теперь пишет "Есть менее 8 блоков вывода", то попытки не разделены новыми строками. По-ходу, я никогда не удовлетворю их запросы((( Спасибо ещё раз, что потратили свое время на решение и объяснение(что особенно ценно)!!! А мне, видимо, надо повторять тему loop for...

Answer (score 3):

вы можете упростить свой код, примерно так:

```
wrd = 'java'  # загаданное слово
out = '-' * len(wrd)  # открытые буквы
att = 8  # количество попыток
while att:  # повторяем пока есть попытки
    print(out)  # печатаем открытые буквы
    l = input()  # ввод буквы
    if l not in wrd:  # проверяем есть ли введенная буква в загаданном слове
        print("That letter doesn't appear in the word")
        att -= 1
    out = ''.join(l if wrd[i]==l else j for i,j in enumerate(out))  # обновляем открытые буквы
    if out==wrd:  # проверяем угадано ли слово
        print(out, "\nThanks for playing!\nWe'll see how well you did in the next stage")
        break
```

ввод, вывод:

```
----
j
j---
a
ja-a
q
That letter doesn't appear in the word
ja-a
v
java 
Thanks for playing!
We'll see how well you did in the next stage
```

Answer (score 1):

Я немного попинал ваш код и вот что из него вышло:

```
import random
list_for_game = ['python', 'java', 'kotlin', 'javascript']
computer_choice = random.choice(list_for_game)
output=[]
print("H A N G M A N")
print(len(computer_choice) * "-")
for hint in range(0,len(computer_choice)):
    output.append('-')
attempt = 8
while attempt > 0:
    count = 0
    letter = input("Input a letter:")
    for j,i in enumerate(computer_choice):
        if i == letter:
            output[j] = letter
            count += 1
    mass = ''.join(output)
    print(mass)
    if count == 0:
        attempt -= 1
        print("That letter doesn't appear in the word")
    elif mass == computer_choice:
        print("Thanks for playing!") 
        print("We'll see how well you did in the next stage")
        break
```

Наверняка найдутся эксперты в сообществе, которые нашли в вашем коде ошибки и наверняка они укажут, куда смотреть. Но если нужна рабочая программа, то вот.

Comment: вместо exit() нужно использовать break

Comment: @Эникейщик скорее можно использовать, а не нужно. Я поправил, но имею в виду, что это ничего не сломает, хоть и правильнее было бы использовать break. Вы ведь имеете в виду, что для выхода из одного цикла не нужно использовать exit()?

Comment: @Сергей Махнёв , огромное спасибо за помощь))))))))

Comment: @ВикаМельникова самому было приятно попробовать сделать ее))

Comment: exit() это вообще не выход из цикла, а принудительное завершение программы

Answer (score 1):

Через неделю мучений все-таки выстрадала код:

```
import random
print("H A N G M A N\n")
list_for_game = ['python', 'java', 'kotlin', 'javascript']
attempt = 8
computer_choice = random.choice(list_for_game)
hint = list((len(computer_choice) * "-"))

while attempt > 0:
   print("".join(hint))
   print("Input a letter:")
   output = input()
   attempt -= 1
   if output in computer_choice:
       for i in range(len(computer_choice)):
           if output == computer_choice[i]:
               hint[i] = output
   else:
       print("That letter doesn't appear in the word\n")
print("\nThanks for playing!") 
print("We'll see how well you did in the next stage")
```

Comment: Главное, что получилось!